# Difference between grep -R (uppercase) and -r (lowercase)

Tags: command-line, grep

If I go into `/etc/apache2/` and type `grep -rl 'LoadModule php' ./*` then I'll only see `./mods-available/php7.0.load`. If I change `r` to `R` then I'll see

```
./mods-available/php7.0.load
./mods-enabled/php7.0.load
```

Both of these are plain directories. I'd expect `-r` to cause grep to recurse all files/dirs in the PWD. What's going on with `-r`? I'm minded to just always use `-R` at this point.

Comment: Thanks all. I was being daft: `./mods-enabled/php7.0.load` is indeed a symbolic link; my original reading of the manual was that `-r` would not recurse through a *directory* if that directory was a symbolic link (but that it would still look through files that symbolic links), so I was confused given that `./mods-enabled` was not a symbolic link.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to [manpage of grep](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/grep.1.html):

> **-r, --recursive**
>                             Read all files  under  each  directory,  recursively,  following
>                 symbolic  links only if they are on the command line.  Note that
>                 if  no  file  operand  is  given,  grep  searches  the   working
>                 directory.  This is equivalent to the -d recurse option.
>
> **-R, --dereference-recursive**
>                            Read  all  files  under each directory, recursively.  Follow all
>                 symbolic links, unlike -r.

**Example:**

I have a folder ***test*** in which there is a file ***1.txt***. ***2.txt*** is a symbolic link to ***1.txt*** such that output of `ls -l test` looks like:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 kulfy kulfy 15 Jun 12 21:53 1.txt
lrwxrwxrwx 1 kulfy kulfy  5 Jun 12 21:53 2.txt -> 1.txt
```

The content of ***1.txt*** is:

```
This is a file.
```

If I want to search for *"file"* string in files inside ***test*** folder and I run:

```
grep "file" test
```

I'll encounter an error:

```
grep: test: Is a directory
```

But if I do:

```
grep -R "file" test
```

I get an output:

```
test/2.txt:This is a file
test/1.txt:This is a file
```

On the other hand if I run:

```
grep -r "file" test
```

I get output:

```
test/1.txt:This is a file
```

Here, I haven't explicitly mentioned to scan all the files. So, when I used `R` flag, symbolic link (here ***2.txt***) was respected and output was generated. But when I used `r` flag, symbolic link was ignored simply because I didn't mention to scan ***2.txt*** also.

Answer (score 5):

From GNU grep [v2.11-8 and above](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/grep-commit/2012-03/msg00048.html), **if invoked with `-r` [excludes symlinks](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#File-and-Directory-Selection)** not specified on the command line  and includes them when invoked with `-R` ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25427188/4970442)).

From [manual page (`man grep`)](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/grep.1.html):

> `-r`, `--recursive`
>          Read  all files under each directory, recursively, following symbolic links only if they are on the command line.  Note that if no file operand is given, grep searches the working directory.  This is equivalent to the -d recurse option.
>
> `-R`, `--dereference-recursive`
>          Read  all  files  under  each  directory,  recursively.  Follow all symbolic links, **unlike `-r`**.